# roots of a fourth degree polynomial function (Vieta)

Tags: polynomials

**Question**

I am interested in the root of the polynomial function :

$x^4+(a+b+c+d-2)x^3+(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-2b-2c-a-d)x^2
+(abc+abd+acd+bcd-ab-ac-ad-2bc-bd-cd-a-d+b+c)x+
abcd-abc-bcd-ad+bc=0$

Under the restriction that: $0<a,b,c,d<1$.

I tried Vietas formula but don’t know how to come to a decomposition

$a_0=abcd-abc-bcd-ad+bc=x_1x_2x_3x_4$

Comment: Have you tried separating into multiple simpler polynomials? You can easily see that parts of the terms come from the decomposition of $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)$... From where does this question come from?

Comment: I tried it and first thought that $(-b)(-c)(1-a)(1-d)$ is the decomposition, but it’s not correct, there are some additional terms in my function. Now i have no idea for another decomposition which fits.

Comment: This is a characteristic function of a matrix and i search for which $x$ the determinant is 0.

Comment: Quartic equations are solved in radicals - e.g., see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html

Answer (score 3):

There are two real solutions, the general expressions are very, very long. Even if all four coefficients are equal, $a=b=c=d$, you have an equation
$$a^4-2 a^3+(4 a-7) a^2 x+(4 a-2) x^3+6 (a-1) a x^2+x^4=0$$
with complicated solutions.

---

For example, if all coefficients are equal to 1/2 the two real solutions are
$$x=\frac{4+6^{2/3}\pm\sqrt{20 \sqrt{4+6^{2/3}}-6 \sqrt[3]{6}+4\ 6^{2/3}+32}}{4 \sqrt{4+6^{2/3}}}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. How do you know there are two real solutions?

Comment: I need the general expression. How can i obtain it?

Comment: Mathematica will readily give you the general expression for all four roots (two real, two complex); the expression for each root is about 250 lines long, what could you possibly do with it?

Comment: I just tried with Mathematica, but I always get an error. :(

Comment: Do you solve it with ‚Roots‘ or with ‚Reduce‘?

Comment: Solve[x^4 + (a + b + c + d - 2) x^3 + (a b + a c + a d + b c + b d + 
      c d - 2 b - 2 c - a - d) x^2
   + (a b c + a b d + a c d + b c d - a b - a c - a d - 2 b c - b d - 
      c d - a - d + b + c) x + a b c d - a b c - b c d - a d + b c == 
  0, x]

Comment: Thank you, but I only see one solution?

Comment: Do you know how i can see the four solutions?

Comment: sol = Solve[.....==0,x];x1=x/.sol[[1]];x2=x/.sol[[2];x3=x/.sol[[3];x4=x/.sol[[4]; then the four variables x1,x2,x3,x4 contain the four solutions; x1 and x2 are complex, x3 and x4 are real.

Comment: I writed sol=Solve[x^4 + (a+b+c+d-2) x^3 + (ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-2b-2c-a-d) x^2 +(abc+abd+acd+bcd-ab-ac-ad-2bc-bd-cd-a-d+b+c)x + abcd-abc-bcd-ad+bc == 0, x];x1=x/.sol[[1]];x2=x/.sol[[2]];x3=x/.sol[[3]];x4=x/.sol[[4]]; but get no Output. :(

Comment: The semicolon suppressed the output.  Try typing x1 (or x2 or x3 or x4) after the program runs.